# How do I calculate the average total per day for a set of data?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a set of data (see image below)

[image]

What I would like to do is calculate the average total for each person per day for the whole date range.

I know that I can go through and tediously do it by calculating the sum for each person on each day and then at the very end get the average for each day on each person, but what I am trying to figure out is if there is a faster or more efficient way to do the same thing. Thank you for any help.

Comment: So you want one row for each person (with the value being the average of the sums per day for that person) or a row for each person x day combo (with the value being the average for that day for that person)?

Comment: @GeorgeS one row for each person (with the value being the average of the sums per day for that person)

Comment: Have you even tried =QUERY("SELECT SUM(…) GROUP BY …") ?